# Rails - map 1 to true in if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, boolean

I am getting a request from mobile app. They are sending a variable `isbookmarked` that can be either `1` or `0`. I am checking in if statement.

```
if isbookmarked
  do something
else
  do something
end
```

The `else` part is never executed because `0` is not recognised as `false`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby everything is truthy except for `nil` and `false`. Thus both `0` and `1` are truthy - you will never reach the `else` part with this set up.

So in your case you want to check exactly for `0` or `1`:

```
if isbookmarked == 1
  do something
elsif isbookmarked == 0
  do something
end
```

Comment: I think, in this case `if isbookmarked == 0` is optional)

Comment: @AlexGolubenko you're right -  in this specific case it is. But I usually tend to double check, so here I'd also have `else raise 'Invalid isbookmarked value'` :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko given the request is coming from an app, it definitely makes sense to raise an error if an incorrect value is passed.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Yeah, your right)
Also, what you think about using `case`  instead `if`, for solve this task?

Comment: @AlexGolubenko `case` would work perfectly fine here :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Thanks! +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this gem called [wannabe_bool](https://github.com/prodis/wannabe_bool), you will get a `to_b` method which can convert almost everything to boolean, you can check the gem documentation for all the options available.

```
if isbookmarked.to_b
  do something
else
  do something
end
```

I have tried few of the things on console that might help you

```
2.0.0-p451 :002 > "1".to_b
 => true 
2.0.0-p451 :003 > "0".to_b
 => false 
2.0.0-p451 :004 > 1.to_b
 => true 
2.0.0-p451 :005 > 0.to_b
 => false
```

https://github.com/prodis/wannabe_bool

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

So, in addition to @AndreyDaineko, you also can use [`case`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-case)

```
case isbookmarked
when 1
  do something
when 0
  do something
else
  something go wrong
end
```

Answer (score 1):

A helper method like below may come in handy.

```
def truthy?(val)
  val.present? && !val.to_s.strip.in?(['false', '0'])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that you should use the same logic that Rails uses to identify booleans. Rails implements [type casting to booleans](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/type/boolean.rb) like this:

```
FALSE_VALUES = [false, 0, "0", "f", "F", "false", "FALSE", "off", "OFF"].to_set

def cast_value(value)
  if value == ""
    nil
  else
    !FALSE_VALUES.include?(value)
  end
end
```

You can use this implementation like this (Rails 5 version):

```
ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(isbookmarked)
```

Or the Rails 4.2 versions would look like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_user(isbookmarked)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`zero?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-zero-3F) to check whether the value is zero or not. But there is no special method to check 1 only way `isbookmarked == 1`

```
if isbookmarked.zero?
  do something
else
  do something
end
```